# How to derive the distribution of the uncertainty of the measurement of vector's components from the distribution of the uncertainty of its modulus?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a real vector
$$
\mathbf{p} = (p_{x},p_{y},p_{z})
$$
representing some observable. Its measurement allows determining the modulus $p\equiv \sqrt{p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}}$ only up to some uncertainty $\Delta p$, i.e. what we measure is
$$
P = p+ \Delta p,
$$
The probability distribution for $\Delta p$ is the Gauss distribution that has $p$-dependent sigma:
$$
f(\Delta p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(p)}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\Delta p}{\sigma(p)}\right)^{2} \right]
\tag 1
$$
Let us assume that the uncertainty is non-zero only for $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$, i.e.,
$$
\mathbf{P} = (p_{x}+\Delta p_{x}, p_{y}+\Delta p_{y},p_{z}) \Rightarrow P = p+\Delta p
$$
Then, my question is: how to find the distribution corresponding to the uncertainties $\Delta p_{x}$ and $\Delta p_{y}$ if knowing the distribution corresponding to the uncertainty $\Delta p$?

P.S. $\sigma(p)$ has the property $\sigma(p)\ll p$. Another property is that $\Delta p_{x}$, $\Delta p_{y}$ are distributed identically.

Comment: @angryavian : $\Delta p$ is a number. It is defined from the scalar quantity $P = p + \Delta p$.

Comment: You would need some additional assumptions, for example is it reasonable to assume that $\Delta p_x$ and $\Delta p_y$ are identically distributed? If you are in some complicated potential this may not be the case.

Comment: @NinadMunshi : thanks, this is an important property. This assumption is really the case.